# How do I order a field's returned objects by default after defining a through model?

Tags: python, django, model, many-to-many

**Summary**

Defining get_queryset() as below is not ordering objects with `order` integer as expected. I expect it to order is item.order1 item.order2 item.order 3, but I actually get 12,1,6. or even 8,13,2.

`return self.items.all().order_by('items','-itemOrder__order')`

**Detail**

I have an `Item` model, and a `Set` model. Set's have a `ManyToMany` relationship with `Item`, so each `Set` is basically a collection of `Item`s.

The issue is, there's no order to these items when I display them, and I want to be able to order them arbitrarily. Ie. not just by date or title.

I've defined a `through` relationship, in which `Set` items are defined through a new class `SetMeta` which has an `order` field. I can now set that `order` in my web app front end, but the actual ordering of the objects hasn't yet worked.

**models.py**

```
class Item(models.Model, AdminVideoMixin):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    ....

class Set(Item):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name='in_sets', through='SetMeta', max_length=5000,)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('curate:set_detail',kwargs={'slug':self.slug})

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.items.all().order_by('-itemOrder__order')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class SetMeta(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='itemOrder', max_length=5000)
    set = models.ForeignKey(Set, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='SetOrder', max_length=5000)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True,)

    def up(self):
        self.order += 1
        self.save()
        print(self.order)

    def down(self):
        self.order -= 1
        self.save()
        print(self.order)
```

**views.py**

```
def setEdit(request, slug):

    set = Set.objects.get(slug__exact=slug)
    user = request.user

   ### SOME OTHER STUFF ###

    return render(request, 'curate/set_edit.html', {'set_edit': set_edit,
                                                    'item_form': item_form,
                                                    'set' : set})
```

**set_edit.html template**

```
  {% for item in set.items.all %}
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 item mr-1 badge-set-holder"  aria-expanded="true">

          {% if item.type == 'video' %}
          <a href="{% url 'curate:item_detail' slug=item.slug %}"><img class='img-fluid img-preview' src="{{item.image_sized.url}}" alt="broken"> </img>
            <span id=dr{{set.pk}} class="badge badge-success badge-set-positioner">Video</span>

#####

  {% else %}
              <a href="{% url 'curate:item_detail' slug=item.slug %}"><img class='img-fluid img-preview' src="{{item.top_image}}" alt="broken"> </img>
              <span class="badge badge-success badge-set-positioner">Item</span>

            {% endif %}

            <div class="collapse show" id=dr{{set.pk}}>
              <a href="{% url 'curate:item_detail' slug=item.slug %}">
                <h5 class='header'>{{item.title}}</h5>
              </a>
              <small>The order is {{item.itemOrder.get.order}}</small>
              <p>
                <a href="{% url 'curate:remove_item_from_set' slug=set.slug pk=item.pk %}" style="color:red;">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="color:red;">
                          remove_circle
                        </i>REMOVE
                  </a>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                  <a href="{% url 'curate:moveUp' slug=set.slug item_pk=item.pk %}" style="color:red;">
                      <i class="material-icons" style="color:red;">
                            arrow_left
                          </i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="{% url 'curate:moveDown' slug=set.slug item_pk=item.pk %}" style="color:red;">
                        <i class="material-icons" style="color:red;">
                              arrow_right
                            </i>
                      </a>
                      </p>
```

I've added a def get_queryset() function which I think (?) is ordering the fields by itemOrder__order, but it doesn't seem to do that. In the front end, I get inexplicable ordering. I can call 'up' and 'down' on my items, and even display the `order` value in the front, which does change, but the ordering changes totally randomly, I can't figure out what logic is being used to order them. I tried to see if the IntergerField was actually something else, like a CharField, but it's not. I looked in the database.

For example, right now, the items are being displayed in order 12,1,6. I can mess around with the values and the order could also be 8,13,2. I've even tried refreshing the page and seeing if the display is changing randomly without the numbers present in order, but nope, they stay in that order until the numbers change, but do not order with a logic I can understand?

Comment: You should show the template where you are iterating over the items. `get_queryset` on a model does not do anything. (Also I'd point out that it's odd to have Set inherit from Item; why have you done that?)

Comment: Everything in the project is a subclass of Item - Item is where I keep things like 'title', 'image', 'link' etc, and then I have 'Article(item)' 'Video(Item)' Podcast(Item) and Episode(Item). Doing it this way has meant I can keep much of the logic driving the site working - there is probably a better way. I had wanted each 'Item' object to be polymorphic, but it looked like it would cause me a headache in the long run. Doing it this way made it feel easier to have logic that worked universally for 'Item' objects.

Comment: The 'type' field is on all Item objects, so I can always get at the native object (to access object specififc fields) with a simple query using Item.slug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you want to make ordering intermediate `Model`, you should create custom intermediate `Model` (explicitly). You have already did it. Also, you are trying to override `get_queryset()` instance method, in your `Model` class, but it does not matter at all. `get_queryset()` is method of `Manager/BaseManager` class, and not `Model` class.

You can try something like this,,,

```
SetMeta.objects.filter(item_id=ITEM_ID).order_by('order')
```

or

```
SetMeta.objects.filter(set_id=SET_ID).order_by('order')
```

Also, it's good idea to use `select_related()` `QuerySet` method to access related objects and avoid a lot of `DB` hits. It performs `SQL JOINS`. Nothing more.

```
SetMeta.objects.select_related('item').filter(item_id=ITEM_ID).order_by('order')
```

or

```
SetMeta.objects.select_related('set').filter(set_id=SET_ID).order_by('order')
```

Also, you can set default ordering rule on `SetMeta` class.

```
class SetMeta(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='itemOrder', max_length=5000)
    set = models.ForeignKey(Set, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='SetOrder', max_length=5000)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True,)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('order',)
```

## Usage in querying

```
items = Item.objects.all()

m2m_model_qs = SetMeta.objects.select_related('item', 'set').filter(item_id__in=items).order_by('order') # performs SQL SubSelect
for instance in m2m_model_qs:
    print(instance) # this is instance of m2m model
    print(instance.item) # this is instance of Item model. you can access columns also. "instance.item.title"
    print(instance.set) # this is instance of Set model. you can access columns also. "instance.set.pk" # for example.
```

Hope, it helps you.

Comment: The last option seems closest to what I want - all ordering to default to that set in the SetMeta - but does this behaviour propagate to my Set class?

I'm serving my Items, via the Set class, like this:

Comment: If you want to sort ```SetMeta``` class, You should work with ```SetMeta``` model directly. Sort from ```ManyRelatedManager``` will not be helpful. I do not think that, it's problem to use ```SetMeta``` class directly. Also, you have ```ForeignKey``` from ```SetMeta``` to ```Item``` and ```Set```. So, no problem.

Comment: for items in set.items.all

Comment: I updated my answer, read ```usage in querying``` part of answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this, it really did help. Realising my model method doesn't overide anything at all...

I defined an 'order' method on my Set class, when I call it,it gives me what I need which is great!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out eventually thanks to help from both contributors above. I just defined a model method on my set which gives me what I need.

```
class Set(Item):
    front_page = models.BooleanField(max_length=300, blank=False, default=False, null=False)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name='in_sets', through='SetMeta', max_length=5000,)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('curate:set_detail',kwargs={'slug':self.slug})

    def order(self):
        return self.items.all().order_by('itemOrder__order')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```